# Retrofit - Enqueue - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val fizzUrl = "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fizzup/files/public/"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    //Instance Retrofit
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(fizzUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    //Instance Api
    val service = retrofit.create(ExerciseService::class.java)

    //Get Request
    val call = service.listExercises()

    //Get execution
    call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Exercise>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Exercise>>, response: Response<List<Exercise>>) {
            val allExercise = response.body()
            if (allExercise!= null) {
                println("All exercises are loaded :")
                for (c in allExercise)
                    println(" one exercise : ${c.name}")
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Exercise>>, t: Throwable) {
            error("KO")
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my main activity. I have a data model : Exercise
and i have an interface ExerciceService.
But i have an issue with the enqueue method that tell me : Expecting member declaration
Therefore I have an other issue on the object : name expected.
But I've looked how to use enqueue and all I see is what I've done.
Thank for reading me and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Please create a meaningful title, that describes your question. Tags shouldn't go in the title at all, let alone be 100% of it.

Answer (score 0):

@Xetiam,

Check if have imported correctly Callback class.

You can also check here. They have great documentation.

https://site-valley.com/2021/02/17/retrofit-android-tutorial-in-kotlin/

Comment: `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`
`import android.os.Bundle`
`import com.example.myapplication.api.ExerciseService`
`import com.example.myapplication.model.Exercise`
`import retrofit2.Call`
`import retrofit2.Callback`
import retrofit2.Response
`import retrofit2.Retrofit`
`import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory`
There are my import. But thanks I'll look what you give to me.

Comment: @Xetiam did it helped?